# Electron-builder: run as admin install in admin user appdata and not current user

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder

I've an electron app that I installed in `$LocalAppdata` folder today. My configuration is as follow today :

```json
"nsis": {
    "oneClick": true,
    "perMachine": false,
    "createDesktopShortcut": true,
    "createStartMenuShortcut": true,
    "runAfterFinish": false,
    "include": "installer.nsh"
}
```

In my installer.nsh file:

```
!macro preInit
  SetRegView 64
    WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "$LocalAppdata\Programs\My App"
    WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "$LocalAppdata\Programs\My App"
 SetRegView 32
    WriteRegExpandStr HKLM "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "$LocalAppdata\Programs\My App"
    WriteRegExpandStr HKCU "${INSTALL_REGISTRY_KEY}" InstallLocation "$LocalAppdata\Programs\My App"
!macroend
```

If I run the installer as normal user (or admin user), everithing works fine and app is installed under `"$LocalAppdata\Programs\My App"` without any problem.

But in case of a normal user who right click on installer then choose "install as administrator", app will be installed inside `$LocalAppdata` of admin account and not the current user. I've tried to find a solution by replacing `$LocalAppdata` by `$PROFILE` but it seems not resolves my issue.

Can I have help please to make it work and use the current user `$LocalAppdata` instead of the admin who give the rights ?

Is there a way to do that by .nsh script ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

This is by design according to Microsoft. A non-admin user cannot elevate themselves, they are forced to pick an Administrator in the UAC dialog and the new elevated process runs as that Administrator (their profile and HKCU).